# What is the proper way to manage credentials in Jenkins shared libraries?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, credentials

I have started to manage multiple Jenkins pipelines for my team. In these pipelines, there is a lot of repeated code. That said, I've started to better follow the [Jenkins documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) and move the repeated code into shared libraries to be used across multiple jobs.

The problem I am facing is deciding how to manage the passing of credentials between job and shared library. Many of the libraries will deal with exchanging data over different web servers. Every interaction with these web servers require either a username + password or some API token for authentication/authorization.

The solution that I know will work is to have every function in the shared library take credentials as a parameter. With that, I can specify my credentials using `withCredentials(...) { }` in my Jenkinsfile. While I'm confident this will work, I'm wondering if this is the best solution.

Since each API (and respective library) will be tied to a single credential, I'm wondering if I can somehow link the library to a single credential in a secure way. Below are two pipeline examples of what I know will work and what I'd like to explore.

What I know will work:

```
stage('promote') {
    steps {
        // known working solution
        interactWithApi1(content1, credentials)
        interactWithApi2(content2, credentials)
    }
}
```

What I'd like to explore from a feasibility standpoint:

```
stage('promote') {
    steps {
        // something I'm inclined to look into
        // where these library(s) already know the credentials
        interactWithApi1(content1)
        interactWithApi2(content2)
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't write 'library per server'. You will most likely have only one library. There's no "respective" library for a given server.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without seeing some sample code that shows the basic structure of your code. A pure textual description is way to blurry.

Comment: @MaratC, what I meant to say there was APIs instead of server. I've updated the language.

Comment: @zett42, I've added some sample pipeline code to better illustrate what I'm looking to explore.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works for us:

```
//vars/interactWithAws.groovy in your library

def call(Map params) {
   withAWS(credentials: 'jenkins-aws-credentials') { 
       s3upload bucket: "myBucket", 
           file: params.file // etc.
   }
```

Credentials are defined in main Jenkins > Credentials.

Might it be that it would work for you, too?